# Java. Псевдографика для игры крестики-нолики с не фиксированным размером поля

Tags: java

Я сделал для доски 3х3 но мне надо чтобы она расширяясь не разваливалась:

```
static void printDesc(char[][] desc) {
            int d = 0;
            System.out.println("y\\x  0:  1:  2:");
            System.out.println("    -----------");
            for (int i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(d + ": | ");
                for (int j = 0; j < desc.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(desc[j][i]);
                    System.out.print(" | ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("    -----------");
                d++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: что значит расширялась, а не разваливалась?

Comment: Ну когда я задаю размер поля не 3 на 3 вся картинка расползается.

Comment: у вас же прямо в коде зафиксировано `System.out.println("y\\x  0:  1:  2:");` и `System.out.println("    -----------");`. эти 2 строки не зависят от размера вашего поля. они и не будут растягиваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void printDesc(char[][] desc) {
    int d = 0;
    System.out.print("y\\x");
    for (int i = 0; i<desc.length; i++)
        System.out.print("  " + i + ":");
    System.out.println("");
    printDivider(desc.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(d + ": | ");
        for (int j = 0; j < desc.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(desc[j][i]);
            System.out.print(" | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        printDivider(desc.length);
        d++;
    }
    }
static void printDivider(int length) {
     System.out.print("    ");
     for (int i = 0; i<length-1;i++) {
         System.out.print("----");
     }
     System.out.println("---");
}
```

для теста:

```
char[][] d = new char[][] {{'x','x','x','x','x'},
                           {'x','x','x','x','x'},
                           {'x','x','x','x','x'}, 
                           {'x','x','x','x','x'}, 
                           {'x','x','x','x','x'}};
```

Результат:

```
y\x  0:  1:  2:  3:  4:
    -------------------
0: | x | x | x | x | x | 
    -------------------
1: | x | x | x | x | x | 
    -------------------
2: | x | x | x | x | x | 
    -------------------
3: | x | x | x | x | x | 
    -------------------
4: | x | x | x | x | x | 
    -------------------
```

для теста:

```
char[][] d = new char[][] {{'x','x'},
                           {'x','x'}};
```

Результат:

```
y\x  0:  1:
    -------
0: | x | x | 
    -------
1: | x | x | 
    -------
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо!